# SFDX Create Org Command fails with Unknown Error Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When I execute command

```
 sfdx force:org:create -f config/performance.json -a EESO
```

I receive an error like this:

> ERROR:  The request to create a scratch org failed with error code:
>   unknown.

My `config/performance.json` looks like following:

```
{
    "orgName": "Client Scratch Org",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["API","AuthorApex","Communities","ContactsToMultipleAccounts","ContractApprovals","CascadeDelete","CustomerSelfService","CustomApps","CustomTabs","DebugApex","DefaultWorkflowUser","ExpandedSourceTracking","ExternalSharing","ForceComPlatform","MultiCurrency","PersonAccounts","SalesWave","LightningSalesConsole","LightningServiceConsole","ServiceCloud","ServiceWave","Sites","StateAndCountryPicklist"],
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["AnalyticsSharingEnable","AsyncSaveEnabled","ChatterEnabled","DisableParallelApexTesting","EnhancedEmailEnabled","EventLogWaveIntegEnabled","LoginForensicsEnabled","NetworksEnabled","NotesReservedPref01","OfflineDraftsEnabled","PathAssistantsEnabled","S1DesktopEnabled","S1OfflinePref","SelfSetPasswordInApi","SendThroughGmailPref","SocialProfilesEnable","Translation","VoiceEnabled","IsAccountTeamsEnabled","ShowViewHierarchyLink","IsActivityRemindersEnabled","IsDragAndDropSchedulingEnabled","IsEmailTrackingEnabled","IsGroupTasksEnabled","IsMultidayEventsEnabled","IsRecurringEventsEnabled","IsRecurringTasksEnabled","IsSidebarCalendarShortcutEnabled","IsSimpleTaskCreateUIEnabled","ShowEventDetailsMultiUserCalendar","ShowHomePageHoverLinksForEvents","ShowMyTasksHoverLinks","AutoCalculateEndDate","IsContractHistoryTrackingEnabled","NotifyOwnersOnContractExpiration","AssetLookupLimitedToActiveEntitlementsOnAccount","AssetLookupLimitedToActiveEntitlementsOnContact","AssetLookupLimitedToSameAccount","AssetLookupLimitedToSameContact","IsEntitlementsEnabled","EntitlementLookupLimitedToActiveStatus","EntitlementLookupLimitedToSameAccount","EntitlementLookupLimitedToSameAsset","EntitlementLookupLimitedToSameContact","IsForecastsEnabled","IsChatterProfileEnabled","IsIdeaThemesEnabled","IsIdeasEnabled","IsIdeasReputationEnabled","IsCreateEditOnArticlesTabEnabled","IsExternalMediaContentEnabled","IsKnowledgeEnabled","ShowArticleSummariesCustomerPortal","ShowArticleSummariesInternalApp","ShowArticleSummariesPartnerPortal","ShowValidationStatusField","IsLiveAgentEnabled","IsMarketingActionEnabled","IsMiddleNameEnabled","IsNameSuffixEnabled","IsOpportunityTeamEnabled","IsNegativeQuantityEnabled","IsOrdersEnabled","IsReductionOrdersEnabled","IsExactTargetForSalesforceAppsEnabled","IsCascadeActivateToRelatedPricesEnabled","IsQuantityScheduleEnabled","IsRevenueScheduleEnabled","IsQuoteEnabled","DocumentContentSearchEnabled","OptimizeSearchForCjkEnabled","RecentlyViewedUsersForBlankLookupEnabled","SidebarAutoCompleteEnabled","SidebarDropDownListEnabled","SidebarLimitToItemsIownCheckboxEnabled","SingleSearchResultShortcutEnabled","SpellCorrectKnowledgeSearchEnabled"],
        "disable": ["S1EncryptedStoragePref2"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosh, I made a typo in my scratch org definition file, I misspelled "Disabled" as "disable"

```
"orgPreferences" : {
    "enabled": ["AnalyticsSharingEnable","AsyncSaveEnabled","ChatterEnabled","DisableParallelApexTesting","EnhancedEmailEnabled","EventLogWaveIntegEnabled","LoginForensicsEnabled","NetworksEnabled","NotesReservedPref01","OfflineDraftsEnabled","PathAssistantsEnabled","S1DesktopEnabled","S1OfflinePref","SelfSetPasswordInApi","SendThroughGmailPref","SocialProfilesEnable","Translation","VoiceEnabled","IsAccountTeamsEnabled","ShowViewHierarchyLink","IsActivityRemindersEnabled","IsDragAndDropSchedulingEnabled","IsEmailTrackingEnabled","IsGroupTasksEnabled","IsMultidayEventsEnabled","IsRecurringEventsEnabled","IsRecurringTasksEnabled","IsSidebarCalendarShortcutEnabled","IsSimpleTaskCreateUIEnabled","ShowEventDetailsMultiUserCalendar","ShowHomePageHoverLinksForEvents","ShowMyTasksHoverLinks","AutoCalculateEndDate","IsContractHistoryTrackingEnabled","NotifyOwnersOnContractExpiration","AssetLookupLimitedToActiveEntitlementsOnAccount","AssetLookupLimitedToActiveEntitlementsOnContact","AssetLookupLimitedToSameAccount","AssetLookupLimitedToSameContact","IsEntitlementsEnabled","EntitlementLookupLimitedToActiveStatus","EntitlementLookupLimitedToSameAccount","EntitlementLookupLimitedToSameAsset","EntitlementLookupLimitedToSameContact","IsForecastsEnabled","IsChatterProfileEnabled","IsIdeaThemesEnabled","IsIdeasEnabled","IsIdeasReputationEnabled","IsCreateEditOnArticlesTabEnabled","IsExternalMediaContentEnabled","IsKnowledgeEnabled","ShowArticleSummariesCustomerPortal","ShowArticleSummariesInternalApp","ShowArticleSummariesPartnerPortal","ShowValidationStatusField","IsLiveAgentEnabled","IsMarketingActionEnabled","IsMiddleNameEnabled","IsNameSuffixEnabled","IsOpportunityTeamEnabled","IsNegativeQuantityEnabled","IsOrdersEnabled","IsReductionOrdersEnabled","IsExactTargetForSalesforceAppsEnabled","IsCascadeActivateToRelatedPricesEnabled","IsQuantityScheduleEnabled","IsRevenueScheduleEnabled","IsQuoteEnabled","DocumentContentSearchEnabled","OptimizeSearchForCjkEnabled","RecentlyViewedUsersForBlankLookupEnabled","SidebarAutoCompleteEnabled","SidebarDropDownListEnabled","SidebarLimitToItemsIownCheckboxEnabled","SingleSearchResultShortcutEnabled","SpellCorrectKnowledgeSearchEnabled"],
    "disabled": ["S1EncryptedStoragePref2"]
}
}
```